# Laravel conditional clause when for filtering value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have a event table with status o or 1.

I have to filter the event with status 1,0 or ALL.

I tried with laravel when conditional clause,its not working with value zero,other conditionals are working.

```
$status    = Input::get('status');
$events    = DB::table('events')
          ->select('events.*')
          ->when($status, function ($query) use ($status) {
           return $query->where("events.status",$status);
           })
          ->get();
```

Comment: Try `$status = Input::get('status') ? 1 : 0;`. The status parameter is probably a string and you only want two options 1 and 0 (a user can change the status parameters)

Comment: Have you read the documentation at https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries? It states that "The when method only executes the given Closure when the first parameter is true. If the first parameter is false, the Closure will not be executed."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`in_array` function used in `when` method try this one

> because 0(zero) means(false) by default understand so try to use inner function in when method
>
> if didn't pass status then set default value as `2` or any number but not `0,1 and null`

```
$status  = Input::has('status') ? Input::get('status') : 2;

$events  = DB::table('events')->select('events.*')
          ->when(in_array($status,[0,1]), function ($query) use ($status) {
                return $query->where("events.status",$status);
           })->get();
```

> second way create a new  function

```
   function checkStatus($status,$array) {
       if(isset($status)) {
           return in_array($status,$array);
      }

      return false;
    }



$events  = DB::table('events')->select('events.*')
                  ->when(checkStatus($status,[0,1]), function ($query) use ($status) {
                        return $query->where("events.status",$status);
                   })->get();
```

Comment: select `events`.* from `events` where `events`.`status` is null; got this when i didnt pass the value

Comment: am using this in a filter section,if am not passing status then the query should work without where condition,other wise with 0 or 1

Comment: @Rp9 also used in second way by create new function and check

Answer (score 0):

For any future reader using 0 and 1

we can use when in the following way

```
->when($request->has('status'),
fn ($query) => $query->where("status", $request->status)
)->get();
```

we are getting the user requested status using has method in Laravel to deal with it.